# How does one perform a regression where one of the inputs only predicts the magnitude of the output?

Tags: regression, modeling

So consider inputs x1, x2 and output y. X1 has a relatively linear relationship with y. X2 has a relatively linear relationship with |y|. How might you perform the regression? If it was the magnitude of x2 that predicted y, you could take the norm of the input, but we can't simply take the norm of the output in this case because that gives up information from x1. And if we added a new dimension to the output, |y|, the output of the regression could violate that condition that the second component is the norm of the first.

Comment: What do you need the regression for. Would it be acceptable, to do it in two steps, like predicting |y| from x1 and x2 and then predicting the sign(y) through a logistic regresison only from x1?